# Вывод постов с одинаковыми рубриками на двух страницах, но с разными метками WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Недавно начал изучать WordPress, и, конечно, у меня появились проблемы. Я создал две страницы: Магазины и Акции. На каждом из них вставил виджет Рубрики и вывел посты через цикл. Но проблема в том, что у Магазин и Акции должны быть одинаковые рубрики, и из-за этого на обоих страницах выводятся все записи с данных рубрик. То есть все записи Магазины и Акции перемешиваются. По сути две одинаковые страницы. Тогда я решил каждой записи прикреплять метку, типа: stock или shop. Прописал этот код в файл category.php, который выводит нужные мне посты с нужной меткой:

```
<?php if(have_posts()){
    while(have_posts()){
        the_post();
        $all_the_tags = get_the_tags();
        if( $all_the_tags ){
            foreach( $all_the_tags as $this_tag ){
                if( $this_tag->name == 'stock' ) {
                    ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                        <div class="stock_carousel_box stock_carousel_box_small content_box-stock">
                            <div class="stock_carousel_box_up">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail('post_thumb'); ?>
                                <div class="stock_carousel_box_circle">
                                    <img src="img/stock/letu.png" alt="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="stock_carousel_box_text">
                                <div class="stock_carousel_box_title content_box_title-stock"><?php the_title() ?></div>
                                <div class="stock_carousel_box_subtitle content_box_subtitle-stock"><?php the_excerpt() ?></div>
                                <div class="stock_carousel_box_date content_box_date-stock"><?php the_time('j F Y'); ?></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <?php
                    } 
                else {  
                    // не найдена ни одна метка
                }
           }
      }
?>
```

Он работает так, как мне нужно: выводит посты рубрик с нужной мне меткой. Но проблема в том, что файл category.php один. А вот это условие if( $this_tag->name == 'stock' ) собственно и выводит нужные мне посты. Но за что мне зацепиться, чтобы прописать условие, где будет меняться значение метки c stock на shop и на оборот. Или вообще можно это как-то по-другому реализовать.

В общем, я в этом мало шарю, и мне кажется, что я там понаписал какой-то бред, но все мне нужно это. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Таки да, бред из-за не понимания сущностей ВП. См https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE/#post-155549. И вообще непонятна задача которую ты хочешь решить придумывая таки кривые пути.

Answer (score 1):

Я нашел ответ на мой вопрос, но забыл сюда написать. Короче, надо было прописать в аргументе для WP_Query этот код:

```
$cat_name = get_query_var('term');
$args = array(
    'название_таксономии' => "'".$cat_name."'",
    'post_type' => 'тип_записи',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Но для этого нужно было зарегистрировать две новые таксономии и создать два новых типа записи. Далее создать два шаблона для категорий:
taxonomy-название_1.php
taxonomy-название_2.php

Ну и естественно, нужно было создать два виджета, где буду выводиться эти такономии на двух разных страницах. get_query_var('term') помогает вытащить выбранную категорию. В принципе, все

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то `is_page()` Вам в помощь.